# Resource blocked due to MIME type mismatch with leaflet map

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, response-headers

I have created a leaflet map onto which I want to plot river gauge statuses from [this NOAA map server](https://idpgis.ncep.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NWS_Observations/ahps_riv_gauges/MapServer/). When I initially load my map I see all the relevant markers with no errors in the console. If I start to pan around the map, however (loading more markers as a result), the points fail to load. Ditto if I remove and re-add the layer.

In my console I see the following errors. Chrome gives me:

```
Request.js:187 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://idpgis.ncep.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NWS_Observations/ahps_riv_gauges/MapServer/0/query?returnGeometry=true&where=1%3D1&outSR=4326&outFields=*&inSr=4326&geometry=%7B%22xmin%22%3A-90%2C%22ymin%22%3A40.979898069620155%2C%22xmax%22%3A-67.50000000000001%2C%22ymax%22%3A55.7765730186677%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A4326%7D%7D&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometryPrecision=6&resultType=tile&f=geojson&callback=window._EsriLeafletCallbacks.c56 with MIME type text/plain. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Firefox raises an error as well:

```
The resource from “https://idpgis.ncep.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NWS_Observations/ahps_riv_gauges/MapServer/0/query?returnGeometry=true&where=1%3D1&outSR=4326&outFields=*&inSr=4326&geometry=%7B%22xmin%22%3A-90%2C%22ymin%22%3A55.7765730186677%2C%22xmax%22%3A-67.50000000000001%2C%22ymax%22%3A66.51326044311188%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A4326%7D%7D&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometryPrecision=6&resultType=tile&f=geojson&callback=window._EsriLeafletCallbacks.c7” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

In both browsers I am able to load the initial view of my map, but then once its loaded and I start interacting with it I start encountering these errors.

I generally understand that the X-Content-Type-Options is causing me this issue. If I look at the response headers in Firefox I can confirm that `x-content-type-options` is `nosniff` and that the `content-type` is `text/plain; charset=UTF-8`.

Since I don't have any control over the server, and therefore can't directly affect the response headers, is there anything I can do to overcome this behavior?

I have created a working [CodePen here](https://codepen.io/jamestollefson/pen/MWeZYEz?editors=0001) that recreates the error. The actual CodePen console won't show the error, but if you open your browser console it'll show up as advertised.

Here's the relevant code:

#### HTML

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
    crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
    crossorigin=""></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/369cdded93.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet@2.4.1/dist/esri-leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-xY2smLIHKirD03vHKDJ2u4pqeHA7OQZZ27EjtqmuhDguxiUvdsOuXMwkg16PQrm9cgTmXtoxA6kwr8KBy3cdcw=="
    crossorigin=""></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet-renderers@2.0.6"></script>
</head
<body>
<div class="col-xl-9 m-0 p-0" id="mapdiv">
  <div id="mapid"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

#### CSS

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(25,26,26);
}

#mapid {
  height:100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

#### Javascript

```js
var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
    center: [63.2008, -155.00],
    zoom: 5,
    dragging: !L.Browser.mobile,
    tap: !L.Browser.mobile,
    scrollWheelZoom: false,
    });

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.jawg.io/jawg-dark/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png?access-token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: '<a href="https://www.jawg.io" title="Tiles Courtesy of Jawg Maps" target="_blank">&copy; <b>Jawg</b>Maps</a> &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 22,
    subdomains: 'abcd',
    accessToken: 'shsyk3yIdzeeE6ZnSv1Da78AItybRtOzvOvOgxaYEJBScuSbR7d2LbMsIKOw1dqN'
}).addTo(mymap);

var riverGauges = L.esri.featureLayer({
    url: 'https://idpgis.ncep.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NWS_Observations/ahps_riv_gauges/MapServer/0',
    ignoreRenderer: false,
    useCors: false,
    cacheLayers: true,
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        layer.feature.properties.gaugelid = layer.feature.properties.gaugelid.toLowerCase();
        layer.feature.properties.url = "https://water.weather.gov/resources/hydrographs/" + layer.feature.properties.gaugelid + "_hg.png";

        layer.bindPopup(function(layer) {
            return L.Util.template(
                `<iframe style="border:none; height:100%; width:100%;" src={url}></iframe>
                `
                ,layer.feature.properties)
        },
        {
            minWidth: 600,
        })
    },
    /*
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                    return L.marker(latlng, {icon:floodIcon});    
                },*/
    attribution: 'River Gauges: <a href="https://water.weather.gov/ahps/region.php?state=ak" target="_blank">NWS/NOAA</a>',
    }).addTo(mymap);

let overlays = {};
let points = {
  "River Gauges" : riverGauges
  };
L.control.layers(overlays, points).addTo(mymap);
```

And for the record, since I know it causes people to fret: the access token I'm using here is a temporary one for this question only. I'll revoke it once it's no longer needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution I've been able to come up with is changing from a `featureLayer` to a `dynamicMapLayer`. This comes with some tradeoffs, however:

#### Cons

- Can't customize the icons
- Difficult to style with css

#### Pros

- Loads faster
- No MIME-type or CORB issues

```js
let riverGauges = L.esri.dynamicMapLayer({
  url: 'https://idpgis.ncep.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NWS_Observations/ahps_riv_gauges/MapServer',
  useCors: false,
  f: 'image',
  layers: [0],
  layerDefs: {0:
             "status IN ('no_flooding') AND state='AK'", //"status IN ('major', 'moderate', 'minor', 'action') AND state='AK'"
             },
  disableCache: false,
  attribution: 'River Gauges: <a href="https://water.weather.gov/ahps/region.php?state=ak" target="_blank">NWS/NOAA</a>',
}).addTo(mymap);

riverGauges.bindPopup(function(error, featureCollection) {
    if (error || featureCollection.features.length === 0) {
    return false;
    } else {
    let gaugelid = featureCollection.features[0].properties.gaugelid.toLowerCase();
    let url = "https://water.weather.gov/resources/hydrographs/" + gaugelid + "_hg.png";
    return L.Util.template(
        `<iframe style="border:none; height:465; width:600;" src={url}></iframe>`,
        {'url':url}                      
    );
    }},
    {
    minWidth: 600,
    },
    );
```